# Return values in order

Tags: c#

Currenty I am having trouble with something I'm work on. What I want to do is while `HasEffect(Buffname`) is `true` I want to return multiple values but one after another but I am unsure how to go about it.

Tldr: I want to return multiple values one after another 1,2,3 without it getting stuck on returning 1st one only.

```
While(HasEffect(Buffname))
   Return Skillname1;
```

Comment: Is there any relationship between the logic in `HasEffect` and the values your want to return?

Comment: returning one after the other implies you want to to something in between. Otherwise it won't matter if you return all instances at once, will it? So unless you don't provide what this "in between" is, it's retty hard to give you a meaningful answer here. Could you elaborate on how you want to use that method?

Comment: How does the function (with the code in the question) look right now? How are you calling it?

Comment: Yes I want to use that skill and when I use it I want the 2nd skill to be the return until I use it and so on

Comment: You have a list of Skillname's or are they variables in the function? (You can edit your question to include more information)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while (HasEffect(Buffname))
{
    some logic
    yield return Skillname1;
    yield return Skillname2;
    yield return Skillname3;
    yield return Skillname4;
}
```

The return type of the whole method must be `IEnumerable<T>` e.g `IEnumerable<int>`, `IEnumerable<string>` etc.

Such a method can be used e.g with foreach loop

```
foreach (var skill in GetAvaliableSkills())
{
    // do something with skill
}
```

Comment: _"error CS1624: The body of 'MethodName' cannot be an iterator block because 'int' is not an iterator interface type"_.

Comment: The return type of the method must be `IEnumerable<int>`

Comment: You might also want to explain how OP can use such a method.

Comment: Done, I believe.

Comment: Yep! Much better.